# Is it a X sync or an X sync 2

Tags: chainring, drivetrain, sram

This chainring is it an X-SYNC or X-SYNC2?

https://www.bike-discount.de/en/sram-eagle-12-speed-chainring-x-sync-2-direct-mount-6mm-offset

It is sold as xsync2 but on the chainring is clearly mentioned as xsync...

Comment: Clearly has the wild new tooth shapes so is xsync2

Comment: Ask them.  That way if the picture is wrong, you have a fallback of "but you said...."   https://www.bike-discount.de/en/contact  or   Hotline: +49 (0) 2641 - 89 00 0